# The site cannot be reached on my workplace network

Tags: google-chrome, connection

I have a strange issue with my website. I have little to no knowledge about networking. I have an application running in PHP and MYSQL. It was working fine until suddenly it stopped working with the error "example.com unexpectedly closed connection" and "ERR_CONNECTION CLOSED". That is on google chrome only and on my workplace network only. When I open it outside, it works ok. I tried other browsers like edge and mozilla; it is working, But with chrome, if I open the website 100 times, it opens around 5 times.

I made sure that the server has no issues and it does not have any connection issues. With some research, I cleared the cache and tried to open it using guest mode. Again sometimes woking and sometimes not.

I contacted IT department, and after some research on the firewall, they added the website as an exception and advised me to clear the cache as well as the cookies.

I cleared the cache and cookies and every single troubleshooting advice possible, but no way.

Would you please give me any insights so that I can fix the issue? Thanks in advance.